# Guitar Tablature: "bis" meaning

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature

I've looked, but Google keeps interpreting "bis" as German(?)
Example:

```
|----------------|-------|-----------------------|-------|  
|-------7-----7--|-------|--------------7-----7--|-------|  
|-------8-----8--|--bis--|--------------7-----7--|--bis--|    
|----7-----7-----|-------|-----------6-----6-----|-------|  
|----------------|-------|-----------------------|-------|  
|--7-------------|-------|---------0-------------|-------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"bis" is just Latin for "twice", it's a pretty common expression in romance language countries, not so much in other ones, I guess. I had never seen it in tablatures before, but I suppose the meaning should be to repeat the previous segment.

Comment: I kinda guessed that, as I know the piece, but was frustrated that I couldn't find any reference to it anywhere. 
Also, I don't speak Latin. :)

Comment: In fact, our word *biscuit* has the Latin meaning of "twice cooked."  :)